# Unable to Extract simple Csv file using U-SQL

Tags: csv, extract, azure-data-lake, u-sql

[I have this csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zsFBO-LPqEBk-V1EVwrVe-VazJZ898WH/view),
Almost all the records are getting processed fine, however there are two cases in which i am experiencing an issue.

**Case 1:**
A record containing quotes within quotes:

```
"some data "some data" some data"
```

**Case 2:**
A record containing comma within quotes:

```
"some data, some data some data"
```

i have looked into this issue, and got my way around looking into quoting parameter of the extractor, but i have observed that setting **(quoting:false)** solves case 1 and fails for case 2 and setting **(quoting:true)** solves case 2 but fails for case 1.

**constraints:** There is no room for changing the data file, the future data will be tailored accordingly but for this existing data i have to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, import records as one row and fix the row text using double quotes (do the same for the commas):

```
DECLARE @input string = @"/Samples/Data/Sample1.csv";
DECLARE @output string = @"/Output/Sample1.txt";

// Import records as one row

@data =
    EXTRACT rowastext string
    FROM @input
    USING Extractors.Text('\n', quoting: false );

// Fix the row text using double quotes

@query =
    SELECT Regex.Replace(rowastext, "([^,])\"([^,])", "$1\"\"$2") AS rowascsv
    FROM @data;    

OUTPUT @query
TO @output
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting : false);
```